# Rails 3.1 cached something that I don't want it to be cached(The lastest 30 posts):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rails-3.1

This is the first time I create a Rails 3.1 application; And 3.1 has many awesome features;

But when I show a list containing the lastest 30 msgs from the server, I always get the same result, with no further msgs appended.

I checked the database from the console, and newer msgs were indeed created.

Please give me some hints to solve it. 
Is there a config to control its behavior?

Addition:
  rails 3.1 seems to cache by default. As usual, I will use an frag cache to cache some code frags, and I can control when I need to destroy the cache;

But in rails 3.1, I don't know what I can do to expire the related cache fragments;

Comment: what kind of caching are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt Rails started caching anything without you explicitly tell him to do so.

Probably you have a limit on your query without sort, so Rails will always fetch the same result set.

Paste some code.